# Adding Ninject to Legacy Project C#

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, ninject

I have just inherited a legacy C# & VB.Net project which I will have to maintain and augment from now how.

There are no interfaces and obviously no Dependency Injection.

The first thing I am thinking of doing is creating interfaces and adding NInject, which would then make it possible to unit test the project eventually.

Is it a good idea or should I leave it alone ?

What are the best practices for implementing DI when it comes to legacy projects.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there's a set best practice, other than use common sense - it's kind of a case by case scenario.  A few important questions to ask yourself:

- How much effort is going to be required to create interfaces for the current classes?
- How much additional effort is going to be required to write proper
  unit tests? Will these unit tests add more value than the time spent?
- How long is this legacy system even going to be maintained? There's
  nothing worse than doing a huge upgrade (requiring testing not only
  by the development staff, but by the product user) to replace it in
  18 months.
- Also, how long has this legacy system been in place
  without issue?  There's no reason to invent work if it appears stable
  and really has low maintenance.

Comment: 1) not much, it's not a big system, i have identified a little more than 10 entities 2) this will be a part time project i may not have to maintain for months and months, but i have a budget to solidify it and some free time as well. 3) this system will not be replaced in the near future and probably not for 10 years 4) there are no issues mostly because the ex developper knew all the ins and outs.. i dont, and the client is willing to finance my learning period, so i figured this would be a good way to do it

Comment: I think all of that makes it a good candidate for doing some IoC, except for point #2: they want you to solidify it.  I would argue there's much better uses of your time than rewriting code, just for the purpose of doing some unit testing.  From their perspective, things like performance, exception handling and additional metrics are much more valuable than unit tests that are only done when code changes (and are much more behind the scenes).

Comment: @RedSoxFred you might also consider a Framework upgrade. It's an easy way to sell them as staying "up to date" and making sure they aren't left on complete legacy systems. Part of that obviously includes testing, which then makes your IoC and Unit Testing a great idea.

Comment: I was gonna upgrade the framework to .Net 4.0 (from 2.0), guess I have my work cut out for me.